# Submit button is refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have a form inside of an mvc project and sending the inputs with post method to the controller. Everything is good if I use a "button", but it keeps refreshing the page if I change it to "submit".

html:

```
<form role="form" id="login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-purple" id="postCode" placeholder="Postcode" value="3208SC">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-purple" id="huisNummer" placeholder="Huisnummer" value="20">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control border-purple" id="eMail" placeholder="EMail" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-zoeken" id="btnZoeken">@ReinisResource.SidebarButton</button>    
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my js code:

```
$("#login").submit(function() {
$("#mapStuff").empty();
$("#items").empty();
$("#historie").empty();

var selectedEmp = $(".drpDown :selected").text();
var postCodex = $("#postCode").val();
var huisNummerx = $("#huisNummer").val();
var eMailx = $("#eMail").val();

$("#empName").html(selectedEmp);

$.post("/Home/GetAddressCount", { postCode: postCodex, huisNumber: huisNummerx, eMail: eMailx }, function (response) {

    if (response.Count === 0) {
        $("#pers-info").hide();
        $("#btn-section").hide();
        $("#multipleAdd").hide();
        document.getElementById('inCorrectInfo').click();
    } else {
        $("#employeesList").hide();
        $("#pers-info").show();

        var houseInfo1 = response.Straat + " " + huisNummerx;
        var houseInfo2 = postCodex + " " + response.Woonplaats;
        $("#perceelInfo").html(houseInfo1 + "<br>" + houseInfo2);
        $("#meldingMaken-btn").addClass("active");
        $("#historie-btn").removeClass("active");
        if (response.Count === 1) {
            $("#multipleAdd").hide();
            reinis.ShowMapStuff();
            reinis.ShowItemStuff();
        } else {
            reinis.ShowMultipleAddress();
        }
    }
});
```

});

If you ask me why I need to change it to "submit" from "button" I wanted to add Jquery validation. And I think submit is better to use it for good coding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is what Submit button does - it submits the form

Comment: That's what submit buttons do, they POST the form.

Comment: Just add return false; as last statement. it will work fine.

Comment: When you properly implement jQuery Validate, it will not "refresh the page".  It will validate and then allow a submit that you can block using the builtin `submithandler`.  Otherwise, not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a submit event, it will submit unless you do `preventDefault` or `return false`, as i can see you need to '$.post` .

So it would be like this.

```
$("#login").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 // followed by your code for $.ajax
});
```

More info- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.

For example: Prevent a submit button from submitting a form ( this is your case).

Answer (score 0):

The [default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) of the `<submit>` and `<button>` element is to submit the form and redirect to another location. In order to prevent the page from being reloaded, make sure to prevent that behavior:

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Your code here
});
```

A slightly less convenient method is to use `return false`, but you have to be careful because it is simply the shorthand of `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`. It will prevent events from bubbling up, so if you are sniffing for events higher up in the DOM tree that originate from the `#login` element they will be lost.

Also, `return false;`, unlike `e.preventDefault()` has to be placed on the last line of the function so that it doesn't stop the function from being executed midway, i.e.:

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
    // Your code here

    // Last line
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's what a submit button *does* :)

You can override this behavior by preventing the default behavior of the event when handling the `submit` event of the form:

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // the rest of the code
});
```

*Ideally*, in order to achieve graceful degradation, the submit button (and the form in general) should still perform the necessary actions for the application by way of posting the form and reloading the page.  So the `form` *should* have an `action` which invokes the server-side operation being invoked.

Then the JavaScript code would override that behavior (using the above method) and provide a more UX-friendly AJAX approach to the operation being invoked.

Both should work, so that JavaScript isn't *required* in order to use the application.